# filter words in one string from the other

Tags: javascript, if-statement, filter

guys. I'm very new to JavaScript and just want to ask how can I filter string 2 words from string 1.

```
string1 = ['mango', 'iPhone', 'banana', 'computer', 'apple', 'keyboard', 'strawberry'];
string2 = ['mango', 'banana', 'apple', 'strawberry'];


const string3 = string1.filter(if (word) {})
```

This is how I came up so far. I'm not so sure what to write in filter() method. (1) I want to say if string 1 words match with string 2 words, (2) then I want to exclude them (3) and I want to have store rest of them in string 3.

It there are other ways to achieve the same result that would be also appreciated.

Comment: please note: `filter` takes a function as an argument - you'll need a function

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter like this

```
const result = string1.filter(word => !string2.includes(word));
```

If you want to remove elements of arr2 and arr3 both from arr1 then my approach would be

```
array1 = ['mango', 'iPhone', 'banana', 'computer', 'apple', 'keyboard', 'strawberry'];
array2 = ['mango', 'banana', 'apple', 'strawberry'];
array3 = ['1', '2', '3', 'iPhone']

result = array1.filter(word => !(array2.includes(word) || array3.includes(word)));

console.log(result);   // ["computer", "keyboard"]
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is the best answer... because it's what I would do :)

Comment: @Jason This runs in `O(m*n)` time complexity. It matters if the array size is huge. There are `O(m+n)` run time algorithms possible. FYI.

Comment: @RahulBhobe Sorry that was my attempt at humor. As far as performance goes I guess there are probably better/more efficient solutions, but for the OP it should more than suffice.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to ask one more question. Let say we have three arrays `array 1 = ['apple', '1', 'iPhone', 'banana', '2', 'samsung', 'grape', '3', 'nokia'] array 2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'grape'] array 3 = ['1', '2', '3']` and I want to exclude array 2 and 3 from array 1 then how would you write code?

Answer (score 1):

If your array sizes are large, the most efficient way to do this is by constructing a hash table (object) from the second string, and then filtering the elements in the first string based on the presence of the element in the hash table.

See code snippet below. The following algorithm runs in `O(m+n)` time complexity, where `m` and `n` are the lengths of the arrays.

```js
const string1 = ['mango', 'iPhone', 'banana', 'computer', 'apple', 'keyboard', 'strawberry'];
const string2 = ['mango', 'banana', 'apple', 'strawberry'];

let obj = Object.fromEntries(string2.map(e => [e, true]));
let res = string1.filter(e => !obj[e]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your variable names don't have spaces. `filter` takes a function as a parameter and returns all elements that return true when run through that function.

```js
string1 = ['mango', 'iPhone', 'banana', 'computer', 'apple', 'keyboard', 'strawberry']
string2 = ['mango', 'banana', 'apple', 'strawberry']

string3 = string1.filter(function(word) {
  return (!string2.includes(word))
})

console.log(string3)
```

This will create a new array (`string3`) from `string1`, while filtering out words that are contained in `string2`.

Comment: If you click on `<>` in editor can make this log to console here in page  for everyone to see results

Comment: Thanks, can I ask one more? Now that I can filter one from the other. How about filter words in two strings from one? `string 1 = ['apple', '1', 'iPhone', 'banana', '2', 'samsung', 'strawberry', '3', 'nokia'] string 2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'] string 3 = ['1', '2', '3']` Should I use if here or filter string 2 first into string 4 then filter string 3 from string 4?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. By the way, strings are a data type with quotes around it, for example: `'apple'` is a string. When you see square brackets with contents inside, it's called an array. Example: `['grapes', 'pineapple', 4,]`

Comment: What you named string 1 and string 2 are actually arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I want to exclude the words from string 2 and string 3 in string 1 and want to get `array 4 = ['iPhone', 'samsung', 'nokia']`

Comment: You can do that by adding a second condition in the function called by the filter method. `let array4 = string1.filter(function(word) {
  return (!string2.includes(word) && !string3.includes(word)
})`

Answer (score 0):

filter array string1 by checking the position of its elements in array string2:

```
string3 = string1.filter(function(val) {
 return string2.indexOf(val) == -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let s1 = ['mango', 'iPhone', 'banana', 'computer', 'apple', 'keyboard', 'strawberry'];
let s2 = ['mango', 'banana', 'apple', 'strawberry'];

|------------|----------------------------------------------------------|
| Vanilla JS | const diff = (A, B) => A.filter( x => B.indexOf(x) < 0); |
|            | let output = diff(s1, s2);                               |
|------------|----------------------------------------------------------|
| Ramda      | let output = difference(s1, s2);                         |
|------------|----------------------------------------------------------|
| lodash     | let output = _.difference(s1, s2);                       | 
|------------|----------------------------------------------------------|
```